# "SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined" in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: dart, speech-synthesis, dart2js

The following Dart code does not work on Chrome or Firefox.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  SpeechSynthesisUtterance speechSynthesisUtterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  speechSynthesisUtterance.lang = 'en-US';
  speechSynthesisUtterance.rate = 1;

  DivElement div = querySelector("#text");
  querySelector('#read').onClick.listen((e) {
    speechSynthesisUtterance.text = div.text;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speechSynthesisUtterance);
  });

}
```

The browser's console displays this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined
```

This was tested on:
Chromium Version (31.0.1650.63) & Firefox (26.0) on Ubuntu 13.10 x64

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What Chrome and Firefox versions are you using?

Comment: Have you tried it directly with JavaScript if it works on your browsers?

Comment: I've updates my question with browsers' info. Unfortunately, I don't know JS and unable to test whether SpeechSynthesis works using JS.

Comment: Of what I read this is available for Chromium >=33, can't remember about firefox.

Comment: I've just installed the latest Chrome release which is version 32.0.1700.77. It has the same issue. I didn't find version 33. Is it in dev channel?

Comment: No idea. I googled because of your question. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API

Comment: Interesting Chrome 33 beta was released today. :) [blog.chromium.org](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/chrome-33-beta-custom-elements-web.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Dart-specific problem. If you try the equivalent JavaScript it will also not work in those browsers since this API does not seem to be fully supported yet. It does work in Dartium though.

Comment: Are you aware of a date for when Speech Synthesis API be supported on either of these browsers?

Comment: Just tested the api in Chrome 33 beta and it works like a charm.